# $S = \{1/n : n \text{ is an element of } \mathbb N\}$ no lower bound and what is $\inf S$

Tags: real-analysis

So I Have to show $S$ does not contain any lower bound. so I start by showing the set $S = \{1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, \ldots, 1/n\}$ and all elements of $S$ are positive. Then suppose by contradiction that $S$ was bounded below. Then by completeness it would have a greatest lower bound $1/a = \inf S.$ Since $1/a$ is the greatest lower bound, $1/(a-1)$ is not a lower bound. so that there exists some $1/m$ in $S$ such that, $1/m < 1/(a-1).$ But then $1/m+1$ is in $S$ and $1/m+1 < 1/a,$ which is clearly a contradiction and therefore S has no lower bound

also I have to determine what is $\inf S$?

so we note all elements of S are positive and greater than 0. So we say for all $D > 0$ for $D$ in $\mathbb N.$ there exists $D + 1> D$ s.t. $1/D+1 < 1/D$ and therefore $\inf S = 0.$

Im pretty sure for the second part I'm supposed to replace $D$ with $\varepsilon$ but Im not sure how to word and conclude it with $\varepsilon.$ my conclusion for $\inf S$ seems weak here too I want it to be more solid.. even tho it seems obvious

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: What do you mean by "has no lower bound"? You yourself noticed that all of it's members are positive. Did you mean that it doesn't have minimum?

Comment: yes has no lower bound mean in other words we are not allowed to write minS. and I think it implies it by the archemedan property.. I just want to make sure what im doing is correct way to solve this problem

Comment: You are mixing up different terms. For every $n\in\mathbb N$, $1/n > 0$, which by definition means that $0$ is lower bound for $S$. On the other hand, $S$ really doesn't have minimum, because if it had, that would mean there is some $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb N$, $1/n_0 \leq 1/n$ which is clearly wrong since you can take $n = n_0 +1$.

Comment: this explanation was very clear thank you

Answer (score 3):

I've already explained in the comments that $S$ is bounded below by $0$ and why $S$ has no minimum, but I will just copy it here for the completeness of the answer:

For every $n\in\mathbb N$, $\frac 1n>0$, which by definition means that $0$ is lower bound for $S$. On the other hand, $S$ really doesn't have minimum, because if it had, that would mean there is some $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb N$, $\frac 1{n_0} \leq \frac 1n$ which is clearly wrong since you can take $n=n_0+1$.

For the infimum part, suppose that there is lower bound for $S$ greater than $0$, say $\varepsilon > 0$. Since it is lower bound for $S$ it means that for all $n\in\mathbb N$, $\varepsilon \leq \frac 1 n$, or equivalently $n\varepsilon \leq 1$. This contradicts the Archimedean property of the reals.

Answer (score 0):

First of all $\forall s\in S: 0<s$, thus $0$ is a lower bound of $S$. Let $l>0$ a lower bound of $S$. Suppose $l\in S$. By the Archimedean Property (A. D.) $\exists n \in \Bbb N: \frac 1n<l$. However $\frac 1n\in S$, so it is contradictory to think an element of $S$ less than a lower bound of $S$. (This prooves that $0$ is the infimum of $S$)
Additionally we can proove directly that $infA=0$ by the characterization of infimum. Let $\epsilon >0$; by A. P. $\exists n \in \Bbb N: \frac 1n<\epsilon$. So we found an element of $S$ less than $0+\epsilon$, which means $infA=0$.